# How to send text to the search field through Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Task:
search FAA in search box :
[image]

I have tried this:-

```
webdriver.select_tabs(search.btnSearch);

Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.id("search-text"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Actions seriesOfActions = builder.moveToElement(searchbox).click().sendKeys(searchbox, "FAA");
seriesOfActions.perform();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search-text\"]")));
element.sendKeys("FAA");
element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

webdriver.enter_key(search.txtSearch, Keys.ENTER);
webdriver.enter_Text(search.txtSearch, "FAA");
webdriver.enter_key(search.txtSearch, Keys.ENTER);
```

Got this error:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

Comment: please provide HTML source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below xpath :

```
(//input[@id='search-text'])[2]
```

and use like :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='search-text'])[2]")).sendKeys("FAA");
```

When you find by this id in console it is giving two elements and first one is not visible but second one is the actual input box.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, Selenium interacts with the browser like a real user would. A real user would not be able to type into a textbox/editbox which is hidden. Either you need to change the visibility of the input, re-evaluate why you need to interact with a hidden element, or use javascript executor to set the value of the input, something like this:

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + textToEnter + "'", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a character sequence to the search field on the website `https://faatoday.com/` you need to induce *WebDriverwait* to wait for the *search icon to be clickable* and then again induce *WebDriverWait* once again for the desired *element to be clickable* and then send the character sequence as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://faatoday.com/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#navbarNav span.sicon-holder.fabutton#searchicon>i.fa.ssearch.fa-search.fa-lg#sicons"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbarNav']//input[@class='search-text form-control mr-sm-2' and @id='search-text']"))).sendKeys("FAA");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: faatoday_search]